# Unknown module(s) in QT: serialport

Tags: c++, qt, module, qt-creator, qtserialport

I use Qt Creator 10.0.1 with Qt 6.5.1 version. I installed QtSerialPort version 6.5.2 from the maintenance tool.

I've added QT += serialport to my .pro file but I get the "Unknown module" error from that.

Do I have to download QtSerialPort version 6.5.1 or are there some steps that I'm missing? I expected that the QT += serialport would work if I had any of the 6.5 versions.

EDIT: The project works now when I changed the whole project to Qt 6.5.3.

```
QT  += core gui
QT  += serialport

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets printsupport

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the 
APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wa,-mbig-obj # This line is for QCustomPlot to work

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    qcustomplot.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h \
    qcustomplot.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building against version 6.5.1, you need the modules from this version. I would switch the whole project to the latest version, i.e. 6.5.3.

Comment: Hi! I switched the project to the version 6.5.3 and now it works. Thank you!